# Issue on Uploading Multiple Images to Server By One Click

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to upload multiple images to server by one click. I am not getting any error on JavaScript console but no images uploaded to the server. Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Here is my HTML markup

```
<form id="uploadimage" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 text-center">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail ">
                    <div class="img-box">
                        <input type="file" class="file" name="image" />                            <img class="img img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 text-center">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail ">
                    <div class="img-box">
                        <input type="file" class="file" name="image" />
                        <img class="img img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit" />
</form>
```

js file as:

```
 $("#uploadimage").on('submit', (function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
         url: "loader.php",
         type: "POST",
         data: new FormData(this),
         contentType: false,
         cache: false,
         processData: false,
         success: function(data) {

         }
     });
 }));
```

and PHP (loader.php) as

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES["file"]["type"])) {
    $validextensions = array(
        "jpeg",
        "jpg",
        "png"
    );
    $temporary       = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $file_extension  = end($temporary);
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 100000) //Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
        && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br/><br/>";
        } else {
            if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
                echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " <span id='invalid'><b>already exists.</b></span> ";
            } else {
                $sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; // Storing source path of the file in a variable
                $targetPath = "upload/" . $_FILES['file']['name']; // Target path where file is to be stored
                move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath); // Moving Uploaded file
                echo "<span id='success'>Image Uploaded Successfully...!!</span><br/>";
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "<span id='invalid'>***Invalid file Size or Type***<span>";
    }
}
?>\
```

[image]

Comment: do you have 2 image filed? and trying to upload 2 files?

Comment: yes the images already on browser. I just didnt add all codes here to keep post simple

Answer (score 1):

**Please refer [this](https://www.codexworld.com/upload-multiple-images-using-jquery-ajax-php/)** .
when you send multiple files, php accept it as an array of files but in your code you are accepting them as a single file.
Also, try to give array of name as

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" id="images" multiple >
```

Comment: 'If multiple files are selected, the string represents the first selected file. JavaScript can access the other files through the input's FileList property." [[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file)]

Answer (score 0):

1. In a form, the name is the identifier of the input. So you should do `$_FILES["image"]` to access your file.
2. When a form have multiple inputs with the same name, it must be name with `[]` at the end (at least in php). So rename your `image[]` in the html source.

Answer (score 0):

first, your file array you are taking in controller is wrong,

```
$temporary       = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

you need to take image instead of file because in form file input name you used is image so,

```
$temporary       = explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
```

then after in your html you can take like this as  **thisisme_22** suggests

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" id="images" multiple >
```

then after in you action php file you can take count of the files and the using for or foreach you can get single file and upload it, like this

```
$count = count($FILES['image']['name']);
for($i = 0 ; $i < $count ; $i++){
    $file = $FILES['image']['name'][$i];
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Rits but where exactly should I use the last PHP part?

Answer (score 0):

check this code and change it as you need

```
$arr =  array();
$arr = $_FILES['image']['name'];

    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr) ; $i++)
    {
            $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'][$i];
            $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'][$i];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'][$i];  

        $responce = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "orders/".$file_name);

    }
```

Comment: remove your loader.php code 
put this code into it and then see what happend,
you need to change  your upload directory path to where you wanted to save your file

Comment: I did but still not uploading any images

Comment: No Error! but not sending any images to server

Comment: $responce = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "orders/".$file_name);

it uploads your image or file to orders directory in your root where your php action file is located.
you need to create there orders directory.

like this, $targetPath = "upload/" . $_FILES['file']['name'];

it uploads your file to upload directory at root. first create upload directory

Comment: I followed all steps you said at your previous post

Comment: okay can you please share screen shots another time what you did?
and hope you have created upload or orders directory.

Comment: no not working! not sure why but not uploading any images

Comment: yeas I did created the order directory

Comment: I just updated the post with the image of all three parts

Comment: can you please share screen shots of your updated code

Comment: you have to take olny one input file cos it uploads multiple do not take multiple as same name,
you have taken two input type file

Comment: but I need to upload images seperatly into browser

Comment: yes it upload seperately you do not need to take same input element both time,
multiple keyword is able to select multiple files

Comment: or if you wan to upload multiple files seperatly
you can take both file name diffrent and upload seperatly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150258/discussion-between-jj-bobo-and-rits).